# How to format date "1594321836292" in React and Graphql

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Server, Graphql and Mongoose on my server and React on frontend. When I query "createdAt" in React I get a date with this format "1594321836292". I have found nothing to properly format this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a unix timestamp. React or Apollo, or whatever is not involved here.

You can easily transform it to a JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```js
new Date(1594321836292)
2020-07-09T19:10:36.292Z
```

Then having this object you can format it as you want using available methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keul, it solved my problem.